# Font Background Color on Desktop - GNOME 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, nautilus, themes, fonts

On the normal desktop, the text comes in white. That's fine, except on light backgrounds. I was wondering if there is a way to make a label appear around the text at all times, as when it's selected.

I did experiment with a gtk.css file in the .config/gtk-3 folder like so:

```
.nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item {background: #999999;} 
.nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item:backdrop {background-color: #999999;}
```

However, this only changes the color of the item when it's selected.

There's been a number of people who've asked this in the past about earlier versions of Ubuntu, but hopefully there's a solution to this problem now.

Answer (score 1):

I see relatively decent text using the Ambiance theme with a light background, the light-colored beaver background available in a default Ubuntu 18.04 install:

[image: Ambiance]

The text visibility is somewhat improved by editing `nautilus.css` in `/path/to/theme/gtk-3.20/apps/`.

I changed

```
.nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item {
    color: @theme_selected_fg_color;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
}
```

to

```
.nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item {
    color: @theme_selected_fg_color;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000000, 0 0 3px #000000;
}
```

[image: MyAmbiance]

Another way to make icon text very visible even with an unmodified theme is just to right-click on the desktop and then to choose `Select All` from the context menu:

[image: Select All]

Comment: How could I determine the theme path?

Comment: @SaidbakR, it depends on where you have your theme. By default, gtk themes are found in `/usr/share/themes`. For example, `/usr/share/themes/Ambiant-MATE-Dark`. The other possibility is to have per-user themes located in `~/.themes`. For example, `/home/dkb/.themes/Cinnamox-Kashmir-Blue`. If you're using Ubuntu, open `GNOME Tweaks`, `Appearance` to see the theme you're using. (I'm not on Ubuntu right now, so the names may not be exactly the same.)

Comment: How to edit style (I mean which selectors/classes to use) of single row of list in nautilus file manager in Ubuntu 20.04 GTK3? I have searched everywhere, but cannot find this information anywhere.